# Plots for values that are discontinued

Tags: data-visualization, scatterplot

I have a series of data that express the change of a quantity over time.
However, one of its characteristics is that at some points of time, there is no data.

If I plot this value over time I have:

[image]

or to see it more clear, if I plot the value for the first 3000 units of time (let's assume seconds) we have

[image]

You can see that the quantity is discontinued (it is not measured) at some points of time and by seeing the X axis I can to some extend see when.

A colleague of mine has taken out all these non existent values and plotted the quantity as

[image]

I have few experience dealing with interpretation and data visualization. My question is, is there some rationale or do we gain something by plotting the distribution this way?

One advantage I could think is that you can see the distribution and outliers clearly but on the other hand the value of the X axis I think lose all its meaning.

Is there any reason we should plot discontinued values like the third plot, or is there some inherent disadvantage to plot them broken (like the first two)?